# Prove sequence $x_n = \frac{3n+5}{\sqrt{4n^2 - 1}}$ is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, monotone-functions, upper-lower-bounds

> Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and:
>   $$x_n = \frac{3n+5}{\sqrt{4n^2 - 1}}$$
>   Prove $x_n$ is a bounded sequence.

How can I show that the sequence is bounded? I was thinking about the monotonicity and ways to use it. Looking at the graph the sequence is monotonically decreasing $\forall n \ge1$.

If I could prove that fact then it would become easier to show that the sequence has an upper bound at $n = 1$ and some lower bound.

To prove monotonicity I've tried dividing and subtracting $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ but the result of those actions is not that easy to handle for me.

I'm not allowed to use methods from calculus.

What else could I try?

Comment: Hint: $n^2 \leqslant 4n^2-1 \leqslant 4n^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x_n=\frac{3n+5}{\sqrt{4n^2-1}}$$
Since $n^2<4n^2-1$ for any $n\ge1$. Then,
$$x_n<\frac{3x+5}{\sqrt{n^2}}=\frac{3n+5}{n}=3+\frac{5}{n}\le8$$
For any $n>0$. On the other hand $x_n$ is strictly positive, thus
$$x_n\in]0,8[$$
hence it is bounded.

Comment: But $x_1 = {8 \over \sqrt{3}}$ which is greater than 4

Comment: Yes! I just edit my post! :) thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 3):

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac {3n+5}{\sqrt{4n^2 - 1}}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{3n+5}{n \sqrt{4 - 1/{n^2}}} = 3/2$$

A convergent sequence is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

$$x_n = \frac{3n+5}{\sqrt{4n^2 - 1}}=\frac{n(3+5/n)}{n\sqrt{4-1/n^2}}$$

Cancel out $n$.

Now note that $$|3+5/n|\leq 8$$ and $$1\leq|\sqrt{4-1/n^2}|$$

so $$|\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-1/n^2}}|\leq 1$$

That means $|\frac{3+5/n}{\sqrt{4-1/n^2}}|\leq 8$

*This is not a sharp bound but it serves the purpose of showing that sequence is bounded.*